# To/on, preposition confusion

Tags: prepositions, idioms

> They beat him till he fell **to** his knees. 
>   They beat him till he fell **on** his knees.

What's the difference between the two?
Are both of them grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

> They beat him till he fell **to** his knees.

since it is an ending state that is *kneeling*.

A better example of using *on* might be:

> He lost his grip and fell **on** his knees.

where the meaning is actually falling and striking his knees.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the idiom, the [FreeDictionaries](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fall+on+knees) says that both are correct.

> fall ***on*** one's knees ***and*** fall ***to*** one's knees

means -

> *to kneel down, usually in respect.*